# How to specify polarization voltage in polarized capacitors in Orcad Capture

Tags: orcad

I have a polarized capacitor like below. it's 1uF and 16V.
[image]

the schematic in Orcad is like this:

[image]

How can I specify that 16V voltage?

Comment: Note: this is not called polarization voltage.

Comment: Technically I didn't know what it is called :)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I specify that 16V voltage?

You do this: -

```
1uF 16V
```

You can even do this: -

```
1uF 16V 10%
```

or

```
1uF 16V 10% TANT
```

or

```
1uF 16V 10% ELECT
```

The value attribute can be however you want it to be.

You can even create new attributes (user defined attributes) than can optionally: -

- Be invisible in your schematic
- Be seen in your BoM.

On a slightly different note, I would change your symbol to more adequately represent the fact that is for a polarized capacitor. I would also make it less wide so that if you needed to show several parallel capacitors on grid, they don't clash or overlap: -

[image]

Comment: When I use `1u 16` it says _unknown parameter_, `1uF 16V` doesn't work either. the only working format is `1u`. I'm using c/ANALOG_P.

Comment: Maybe you are using a text/value field that is linked to some data base? It certainly works on OrCAD when there is **NO LINK** to the [CIS (component information system) data base](https://www.orcad.com/sites/orcad/files/resources/files/OrCAD_Capture_CIS_DS_Final.pdf).

Comment: I don't know really. [link](https://imgur.com/a/8e4ibNT) this is how I'm doing it.

Comment: I tried using `C_elect` but it didn't work either.

Comment: That picture looks like normal OrCAD without CIS. Try creating a user defined label and see what happens.

Comment: I have a deadline in 3 hours :))) isn't there any workaround to achieve the same effect as electrolytic capacitor?

Comment: Try a user defined label. User defined labels can be picked up in BoMs if that is required.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it.

Comment: Also double check that you are not trying to alter the reference designator. It has to be a strict format like C1 or C2 etc... if you are using orcad sim then the value has to be not including extra details like voltage. The sim is not orcad capture.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select component
2. Click right mouse button & select "Edit properties..."
3. New property
4. Edit / Enter value
   [image: Add property]

[image: Property applied]